# Why am I seeing "Error - Only secure origins are allowed" for my service worker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, progressive-web-apps

When I try to add a service worker on my progressive web app page, why does the browser console show the following error?

```
ERROR "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Only secure origins are allowed
```

JS Code:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    // TODO add service worker code here
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker
            .register('service-worker.js')
            .then(function () {
                console.log('Service Worker Registered');
            });
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using 
http://127.0.0.1:8080 for hosting locally
instead of 
http://192.168.29.53:8080

Answer (score 22):

From [Service Worker FAQ](https://www.chromium.org/blink/serviceworker/service-worker-faq):

> **Q: I get an error message about "Only secure origins are allowed". Why?**
>
> **A:** Service workers are only available to "secure origins" (HTTPS sites, basically) in line with a policy to prefer secure origins for powerful new features. However http://localhost is also considered a secure origin, so if you can, developing on localhost is an easy way to avoid this error.
>
> You can also use the `--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure` command-line flag. This flag must be combined with a `--user-data-dir` flag. For example:
>
> ```
> $ ./chrome --user-data-dir=/tmp/foo --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=http://your.insecure.site
> ```
>
> If you want to test on https://localhost with a self-signed certificate, do:
>
> ```
> $ ./chrome --allow-insecure-localhost https://localhost
> ```
>
> You might also find the `--ignore-certificate-errors` flag useful.

Answer (score 7):

in chrome type `chrome://flags`

search **"secure origin"**

[image]

then click on **Enabled**, relaunch chrome.

Comment: That totally makes sense, that it would fix the problem - but at least in my case it didn't work. Any suggestion why's that?

Comment: It says "Treat GIVEN (insecure) origins as secure origins" -> in addition to enabling the flag, you must enter allowed addresses, for example: http://192.168.29.53:8080

Answer (score 3):

You can check for protocol before registering the service worker like this,

`location.protocol === 'https:' && serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')`

Answer (score 1):

1. type url

   chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure
2. Enter url in the textarea
3. Choose Enabled in the select option look at the image to see detail

[image]